# Cannot get image data (base64) from textarea second time after submitting form using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am getting image data in base64 format from hidden textarea and that value
is getting saved through ajax and image is beign generated for the first time i 
submit form using ajax, in the ajax success method i am getting new image url 
that i show using $('.contained').attr("src",data); but for the second time 
when i upload the image i did not get the value in the textarea so no image 
is beign generated, but as i  refresh my page and then submit again then it
is working properly i don't want to refresh the page. Please help to sort out my issue.

> View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#upload_course").on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var txtareaval = $('#image_source').val();

    var baseurl="<?php echo base_url(); ?>";

    var formData = new FormData($("#upload_course")[0]);

 $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>upload_course_image/do_upload",
        type: 'POST',
        async : false,
        cache : false,
        contentType : false,
        processData:false,
        data: formData,
        success: function(data){

        $('.loader').show();
        $('.contained').attr("src",data);
         setTimeout(function () {
           $('.loader').hide();
           $("#show_image_preview").show();
         }, 1000);
       },
    error: function(){                      
       alert('Error while request..');
       }
   });
});
</script>

<form  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="upload_course" action="<?php echo site_url('upload_course_image/do_upload'); ?>"> 
<input type="hidden" name="c_id" value="<?=$result;?>" />
<img class="contained" data-purpose="image-preview" style="max-width:500px;width:500px;height: 300px;" src="<?php echo $image; ?>" />
<textarea id="image_source" name="test" style="display:none"></textarea>
<input type="File" name="course_img" id="course_img"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn btn-success" id="submit-id-submit"/> 
</form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the current time to end of your image like this

```
$('.contained').attr("src",data + '?' + new Date().getTime()).show());
```

Comment: No the issue is image is not getting saved for the second time i upload it.Till i refresh the page.

Comment: alert("txtareaval "+txtareaval ); shows blank value

Comment: I think because your not setting a value to txtareaval. so obviously it's blank. `<textarea id="image_source" name="test" style="display:none"></textarea>` while here `var txtareaval = $('#image_source').val();`

Comment: I am using jcrop here and i am setting it through $('#image_source').text(canvas.toDataURL());

Comment: There's a lot of error here in your code. Like this `var formData = new FormData($("#upload_course")[0]);` you don't specify what's the tag/index of it .. it should be something `new FormData('file', $("#upload_course")[0])`. Plus, You don't need to use <form> if you're using AJAX. Lastly, the redundant use of `base_url()`. Actually, you can use just JS `window.location.origin`

Comment: You have to learn JS and AJAX concept thoroughly first for you to lessen these little problems in your code that may affect your goal.

Comment: I have tried first time it is working properly but second time if i want to update that image without page refresh then image data can't be get inspite of textarea containing image data when i inspect element

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105868/discussion-between-user3653474-and-rmondesilva).